# Monitoring long running Celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I am working on a Python platform. The platform will be running on a remote server. A client CLI (from user's computer) will trigger some long-running tasks (which will be off-loaded onto Celery workers) on the server using REST API. 
My question is, from the CLI, how do I monitor the current status of the long-running task? (I can create a REST endpoint which can be polled by the CLI to get status. But I am looking for better ways to do it since polling might overwhelm the server)

Comment: I think the polling is the easiest thing you can do. If you have problems with performance (which you shouldn't, depending on your broker and setup), you can always cache the endpoint.

Comment: I used `text/event-stream` or **Server-Sent Events** which was introduced in HTML5 I guess.. I believe SSE is better in terms performance since single connection is held open until server closes it. So, no polling overhead.